# Getting a CS0121 error in the ConfigureServices method in my Web API's Startup class

Tags: c#

I've been following a tutorial on build Web API's using .NET Core 2.2. I am using .NET 5. I believe there must be different enough changes that the error I'm getting, I wouldn't be getting if I were using .NET Core 2.2, but I don't know where to make the necessary change(s). I've searched here on Stack Overflow, but haven't found anything that addresses the error I'm getting in the way I'm getting it. Here's the code in my ConfigureServices method in my Startup class:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<JobSearchContext>();
    services.AddScoped<IAuthorizedUserRepository, AuthorizedUserRepository>();
    services.AddAutoMapper(); //CS0121 error occurs here
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

The text of the error I'm getting is this:

> CS0121    The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAutoMapper(IServiceCollection, params Assembly[])' and 'ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAutoMapper(IServiceCollection, params Type[])'

What has changed between .NET Core 2.2 and .NET 5, such that the call to AddAutoMapper in my ConfigureServices method raises error CS0121?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use net 5 try this

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

But first create a class that inherits from the Profile class in AutoMapper

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile 
{
   public MappingProfile()
   {
      CreateMap<class, classDto>();
   }
}
```

startup  option shows that this profile will  be  in the same assembly